# Are synthetic oils more resistant against thickening in cold temperatures?

Tags: oil, heater, cold-start, cold-weather

I have heard that each cold start of the engine adds 100km to it's wear due to issues with the cold oil, which is why pre-heating of the engine is recommended to maximize it's lifespan in colder environments. However, some say that this is an old philosophy and doesn't hold true for modern synthetic oils as they are less likely to lose viscosity in cold. Is this true and should engine be pre-heated? Temperatures where I live typically peak at around -20C to -25C at winter.

Comment: It would be wiser not to listen to hearsay than searching for factual info. Synthetic oils are formulated to meet engine manufacturer's specifications for specified operating conditions.  In subfreezing conditions, engine, coolant and battery heaters reduce loads on oil and battery demands. Using oil designed for subfreezing temps with engine/battery heaters will prolong both. Ask locals and repair shops for ideas, suggestions, best methods for low temperature operation.

Comment: Oils have gotten much much better over the last 20+ years. Use what the manufacturer recommends. But, yes, multi-temperature rated oils are common now particularly in synthetics. My truck specifies one 'weight' of oil for all normal conditions in the lower 48 states in the US (Prudhoe Bay might be a different story.